# How to read and write "Unicode (UTF-16 little endian)" text to and from a binary file in Python?

Tags: python, utf-16

I have a binary file "x.bin" which is a windows executable.

I am trying to modify a value of a string inside this executable using Python, viewing this string in a text editor I am told that the text encoding is "Unicode (UTF-16 little endian)" and I can see null bytes wrapped around the text in the string.

However, when I attempt to read from this file in binary mode in Python and I then convert it to hexadecimal, I am told that the hex is not present in the file when doing `print("10002000" in _hex)` and therefore cannot replace any data.

I also cannot access the file in the `"r"` mode using `encoding="utf-16-le"` as this would attempt to decode the data and would fail.

Is there a way to access binary data using the UTF-16 encoding in Python?

Edit:

_hex is the result after calling data.hex()

I am using this method for reading from the file

```py
with open("resources\\rfreeze.bin", "rb") as f:
    data = f.read()
```

Comment: We need a [MCVE] of how you're reading the file in binary mode, how `_hex` is defined (is it actually the raw `bytes` read, or the result of calling `.hex()` on those raw `bytes`, or something else?), etc. We can't debug code you haven't provided. Edit the code into the question, as text, with example inputs, expected output, and observed behaviors please.

Comment: UTF16 is text, not binary. You can't just modify a binary executable and expect it to run. Even if you don't accidentally overwrite executable code, the application may not run eg because the antivirus will detect the change and consider it tampering, or the application itself may be digitally signed and detect it was tampered with.

Comment: It's unclear what you mean `hex` too - bytes are bytes. HEX is a string representation of a byte value.  If you want to find a string in a binary file you need to convert that string to bytes first.

Comment: Your text editor might guess that it's a text file encoded in "Unicode (UTF-16 little endian)" but since it's a Windows executable your text editor is wrong.

Comment: _hex is the result of calling .hex()

The entire file is not UTF 16, just a singular string which I searched for using a hex editor.

Comment: It is not a third party program I am modifying. I have compiled the executable myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is a bit unclear, but to edit an executable you simply need to replace the target bytes with another set of bytes of the same length.  Here's an example:

test.c - Simple program with an embedded UTF-16LE string (in Windows, anyway):

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    wchar_t* s = L"Hello";
    printf("%S\n",s);
    return 0;
}
```

test.py - replace the string with another string

```py
with open('test.exe','rb') as f:
    data = f.read()

target = 'Hello'.encode('utf-16le')
replacement = 'ABCDE'.encode('utf-16le')

if len(target) != len(replacement):
    raise RuntimeError('invalid replacement')

data = data.replace(target,replacement)

with open('new_test.exe','wb') as f:
    f.write(data)
```

Demo:

```
C:\>cl /W4 /nologo test.c
test.c

C:\>test.exe
Hello

C:\>test.py

C:\>new_test.exe
ABCDE
```

Comment: What if the lengths were different, would it be impossible to do?

Comment: @Resist Shorter could work, if the string is null-terminated and the null is copied (it isn't in the above demo), but longer would overwrite unknown parts of the executable data.